# What formatting syntax can I use in tooltip content in Anycharts extension for Qlik Sense?

Tags: qliksense, anychart

I am trying to create some custom tooltip content in the Anycharts Qlik Sense extension.
By default the Tooltip has the Series values.

[example default tooltip](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3bVsq.png)

I have tried various formatting syntax based on the Anychart documentation such as:

1) For {%Dimension} : which shows [tooltip with no data value](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IfCw6.png) where category is the x value

2) "For the x value {%Category}" which shows "For the x value {%Category}"

3) "{%Category}" which shows ""

Does the formatting use Anycharts or maybe d3 formnatting ?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

The AnyChart Qlik extension supports AnyChart string tokens. You can learn more about them in [the article](https://docs.anychart.com/Common_Settings/Text_Formatters#tokens_list).

Here is a sample of valid string token to show the value and x category in custom tooltip content.
[image]